# Sphinx, ReadTheDocs and package version

Tags: python-3.x, package, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I maintain a package whose documentation I auto-generate with Sphinx on readthedocs.org. For Sphinx/readthedocs I use a `conf.py` and a [properly defined](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html) `.readthedocs.yaml`.

Inside the `conf.py` I use the version:

```
import pybliometrics

version = pybliometrics.__version__
release = pybliometrics.__version__.replace("_", "")
```

The version is generated in `pybliometrics/__init__.py`. The package itself uses its own version somewhere in the code as well.

When I do the versioning with `pbr` ([Python Build Reasonableness](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/)) like

```
from pbr.version import VersionInfo

_v = VersionInfo('pybliometrics').semantic_version()
__version__ = _v.release_string()
```

then the build process on readthedocs works without any problem (assuming I make it install `pbr`).

However, when it looks like

```
from importlib.metadata import version

__version__ = version("pybliometrics")
```

then the build process **fails** with `importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for pybliometrics`. Same for `importlib_metadata`.

What's happening there? The reason I switched to `importlib.metadata` is that I can do the the entire build process with `setuptools_scm` and get rid of `setup.py` and `setup.cfg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you need to do `pip install -e` equivalent in your RTD `requirements.txt` build file.

[See .readthedocs.yml example here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/.readthedocs.yml) and [see requirements.txt here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/docs/requirements.txt).

Comment: What should go in there? Currently I have `docs/requirements.txt` to install sphinx and two sphinx extensions. I tried putting `importlib`  or `importlib_metadata` in there without luck.

Comment: See `-e .` on the last line of the example requirements.txt

Comment: I overlooked `-e .` and this seems to have solved my problem